# Find differents range in a time sequence

Tags: r

I would like to know how to find several range in a time sequence.
I've got this time sequence :

```
DATE

1 1996-01-01
2 1996-01-02  
3 1996-01-03  
4 1998-07-13    
5 1998-07-14  
6 1998-07-15  
7 2000-05-28
```

I would like to have all time range like that :

```
[1] "1996-01-01" "1996-01-03"
[2] "1998-07-13" "1998-07-15"
[3] "2000-05-28"
```

Does someone know how to do?
Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to create a grouping column by taking the difference of adjacent elements and use that create the range

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(DATE= ymd(DATE)) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(DATE) > 1))) %>% 
  summarise(min = min(DATE), max = max(DATE))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    grp min        max       
#  <int> <date>     <date>    
#1     1 1996-01-01 1996-01-03
#2     2 1998-07-13 1998-07-15
#3     3 2000-05-28 2000-05-28
```

---

Or with `base R` using `split`

```
lapply(with(df1, split(DATE, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(DATE))  > 1)))),  
          function(x) unique(range(x)))
#$`1`
#[1] "1996-01-01" "1996-01-03"

#$`2`
#[1] "1998-07-13" "1998-07-15"

#$`3`
#[1] "2000-05-28"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DATE = c("1996-01-01", "1996-01-02", "1996-01-03", 
"1998-07-13", "1998-07-14", "1998-07-15", "2000-05-28")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```